# How to get a ValidationError for a UniqueConstraint in Django 4.1+

Tags: django, validation, unique-constraint

Since Django 4.1, constraints are supposedly [checked during model validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/constraints/)*.
I therefore expected a `ValidationError` for a `UniqueConstraint` on a model, when I try to create a new entry through a standard `CreateView` (not using a custom `Form`) that violates the constraint. I was hoping that the create form would be presented again, adorned with an error message, just like a violation of the `unique=True` setting of a model field does.

However, I get an `IntegrityError` instead (resulting in a 500 Internal Server Error), implying that the validation never took place and the constraint was only found to be violated on database creation.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

The Model looks something like this:

```py
class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [models.Index(fields=['name'])]
        constraints = [models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['name', 'parent'], name='unique_ChildName')]
```

(* *Older versions didn't do this, expect for the `UniqueConstraint` constraint under specific circumstances, and there are other StackOverflow questions for doing this yourself, e.g.*

- *[Django unique constraint + form errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3473165)*
- *[How to validate uniqueness constraint across foreign key (django)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14470585)*
- *[UniqueConstraint in django 2.2 don't raise ValidationError](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57070616)*
- *[django: ValidationError with UniqueConstraint on Model.Forms, clean()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60940469) .*

*But that situation has changed since Django 4.1 and my question is specifically for Django 4.1+*)

Edit: based on [Willem Van Onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem%5D)'s comment, I have added the `parent` field to the form fields. But in order to have it be immutable, I made the Form look like this:

```py
class ChildCreateForm(ModelForm):
    parent = ModelChoiceField(queryset=None, disabled=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = ['parent', 'name']

    def __init__(self, parent_id=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['parent'].queryset = Parent.objects.filter(pk=parent_id)
        self.fields['parent'].initial = parent_id
```

and this on the View:

```py
    form_class = ChildCreateForm
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['parent_id'] = ... # some project-specific logic
        return kwargs
```

Comment: Can you show the view and form you use? I assume that or the parent or the name is not part of the form?

Comment: You are right, the parent is not part of the form. When I add it, I get the ValidationError. Is there a way to keep that without including the parent as a field?

Comment: can you share the view and form?

Comment: I have. If you want to post your original comment as an answer, then I will accept it as the solution.